# Woocommerce Shop Template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, canvas, woocommerce

This is pretty straight forward. I've installed the Woocommerce Canvas theme and want to use it to implement an HTML template using the various hooks available. I've set my front-page to be the shop page but cannot seem to find the template which affects the shop page.

I have already tried to change both archive-product.php files, and neither are responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find it myself. The WP Cache plugin interfered.